# Create a complicated matrix from vector in r

Tags: r, vector, rep

I have a vector of sample sizes for 4 populations: 3 2 1 4 which sums to 10 individuals. I need code that can dynamically (so can be used in different situations) make a matrix of 1's and 0's with 10 rows and 4 columns that has 3 1's then the rest of that column 0's then the next column has 3 0's then 2 1's then the rest 0's and so on as shown below:

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
```

Input:

```
nSamples <- c(3,2,1,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible two-step approach.

```
# create a matrix of zeros first
m <- matrix(0L, ncol = length(nSamples), nrow = sum(nSamples))
# then replace relevant 0s with 1s:
m[cbind(1:nrow(m), rep(seq_along(nSamples), nSamples))] <- 1L
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    1    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    1    0
# [7,]    0    0    0    1
# [8,]    0    0    0    1
# [9,]    0    0    0    1
# [10,]   0    0    0    1
```

The "trick", if you will, is

```
rep(seq_along(nSamples), nSamples)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a design matrix by using `model.matrix`

```
f_nSamples <- factor(rep(nSamples, nSamples), orderd=TRUE)
model.matrix(~f_nSamples-1)
##    f_nSamples1 f_nSamples2 f_nSamples3 f_nSamples4
## 1            1           0           0           0
## 2            1           0           0           0
## 3            1           0           0           0
## 4            0           1           0           0
## 5            0           1           0           0
## 6            0           0           1           0
## 7            0           0           0           1
## 8            0           0           0           1
## 9            0           0           0           1
## 10           0           0           0           1
## attr(,"assign")
## [1] 1 1 1 1
## attr(,"contrasts")
## attr(,"contrasts")$f_nSamples
## [1] "contr.treatment"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner with `sparseMatrix`

```
library(Matrix)
m1 <- sparseMatrix(i = seq(sum(nSamples)), j = rep(seq_along(nSamples), nSamples), x = 1)
as.matrix(m1)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    1    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    1    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    1
#[8,]    0    0    0    1
#[9,]    0    0    0    1
#[10,]   0    0    0    1
```